# preventDefault() won't work on delegate target?

Tags: jquery

I have a button which submits a form

the button is on the page already.

So if I want to prevent the submission , I can do :

`$(".myBtn").on('click',function (e){ e.preventDefault();.....});`

But if the button is about to be injected in the future , I can do :

`$("body").on('click',".myBtn",function (e){ e.preventDefault();.....});`

but it is not working and the form submits.

How can I achieve my goal in a case where a handler is not attached directly to the element itself but to a delegate target ?

Comment: Perhaps try using the submit event on the form element.

Comment: That should't make any difference, if you put a breakpoint your click handler, probably won't be called. Are you 100% sure the class is `myBtn`?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi positive. it doesnt work when I do the "live ver 1.9" syntax

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/BQcnj/

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: @JoeSpurling 1.8..............

Comment: undefined's jsfiddle worked for me too: http://jsfiddle.net/Jolora/BQcnj/1/ Have you got a link to your version?

Comment: The exact behavior might depend on the browser. undefined's fiddle also works for me (on Firefox) because apparently event bubbling is performed before the default behavior is triggered. Maybe other browsers perform the default behavior before bubbling, which would explain Royi's problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never attach a click handler to a submit button in order to prevent the submission of a form. Always bind the "submit" event of the form - what if a user pushes enter to submit the form instead of clicking?

```
$(document).on('submit','#your-form',function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

As for answering your direct question, your code should work fine. Make sure your button has the proper class name and make sure that no JS errors occur on your page before or after you are clicking the button that might cause e.preventDefault() to get ignored.

Comment: This DOES NOT WORK.  A delegated submit event is not cancellable.  It's clearly a bug in jQuery.  By the time you hit that e.preventDefault call, the form will have already posted to the server.  That's not the case when you bind directly to the form element itself.